# With blueimp file upload, how can I detect when all files in the upload queue have completed?

Tags: file-upload, blueimp

It appears as though the done and fail callbacks are called for each individual file. After reading the docs, I couldn't find a callback that is only fired when the request queue empties. Has anyone managed to work around this? Or perhaps I'm just missing something obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out the start and stop callbacks are what I was looking for. The documentation describes them as simply being equivalent to ajaxStart and ajaxStop but it appears they are called when the first upload starts or the last upload ends.

Comment: It is indeed what ajaxStart and ajaxStop events are supposed to do. It was confusing to me also, but the documentation says that http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/  http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/